# I feel like my boss is being disrespectful to me, how should I handle it?

Tags: management, resignation, workplace-rhythm

I am a newly appointed temporary teacher at a University and I have an issue with attitude from my boss from the very start. Some of the issues are as follows

- He rarely talked to me nicely.
- When he was distributing subjects, I asked for one in which I am an expert but he rejected my request.
- He mostly assigned me the works of lower staff. E.g. to maintain course files; tagging course files and other work which is not my responsibility
- When I tried to do one of these jobs and I mentioned that the clerks should do it as I am unable, he insulted me and swore.

I am now thinking of resigning from my job as I don't feel like my boss is respecting me.

Is there any way to deal with this kind of behaviour, or is my best option to resign?

Comment: "other work which is not my responsibility" - I hear this a lot from people. Job responsibilities don't just end at the end of the bulleted list of a posting. They typically end with "and other duties as assigned". Your responsibilities include whatever work your supervisor/manager has assigned to you. If you don't like those tasks, then Joe Strazzere has the option for you in his comment above.

Comment: The problem is not in the task that is assigned to me, I am continuously showing a behavior of YES sir, but He insulted me for no reason. He asked me to do Tagging, I couldn't do that. So said that Sir clerks can do that so them please. And in response he shouted alot.

Comment: I hate to say, but the list of points sounds like a bad employee. Point 1 could be that he is just grumpy (happens, some people are not happy smilers all the time), but the other points - what the h*** do you expect as NEWLY appointed TEMPORARY teacher? This is if i read this right "bottom of food chain in the teacher pool".

Comment: I am again telling you that I was doing all the assigned task from the start without complaining. But noticed his disrespectfulness. He is not happy with me in any situation. Thats the problem. The work I asked him to do clerks, I tried but couldn't succeed. And he insulted me in that response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you decide to leave this job, I suggest you try something: give the boss another chance.

NOTE: You didn't say whether the college has a fixed list of subjects which they must teach. You didn't say whether your boss gave your favorite subject to somebody else. Or did he reject your subject because it would be a new offering? The two are different. Where I live (USA) most temporary college teachers, as a fact of life, get the subjects nobody else wants. (Exception: If Albert Einstein were the temp, they would let him teach Special Relativity as long as he also taught Physics Without Calculus.)

Ask your boss for a short private conversation. Say something like this.

> I'm sorry I annoyed you with my question about whether the clerks should do the  filing tasks, instead of me.
>
> Here's why I ask: I wonder why you rejected my offer to teach the course on my favorite subject, *hyperfractal geometry in nature*. If you gave me the chance to teach it, I'm sure our students would learn a lot.

and

> Please help me set my expectations. My hope for my job is to do a lot of teaching, but you have me doing administration.  Is it possible for me to do more teaching in future?

If you possibly can, set aside your annoyance with him, and talk over the mismatch between your's and his's understanding of your job.

If your boss won't have that conversation, or is rude again, then consider leaving the job.

Comment: Just my opinion, but if my boss insults me just once, I'd just start hunting for other job ASAP. It's highly unprofessional to have management mistreating employers, period.

Comment: The subject he didn't assign me, I have done masters in that subject. The reason of not giving me the subject is his personal feelings. All members were agreeing on giving me that subject but he discarded me.

Comment: Now my boss is not talking to me. How rude, he shouted and showed the disrespectfulness without any reason and he is making faces like mistake is mine. Why God created these bosses.

Answer (score 3):

I'm no expert, but it sounds like you didn't discuss your job responsibilities with your boss before getting hired.

Nevertheless, it's clear that your boss showed disrespect to you, as swearing and insulting is completely unprofessional. And from what you said, he's not the kind of person that will be eager to talk about how much the tasks given to you don't match your expectations.

In this case, it would be better to leave your job (after finding a new one of course). In the meantime, just bear with him.